# C# and SQL data duplication

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have code that is pulling information from SQL server and displaying information about cars.

The problem is that the data is displayed but duplicated. The SQL Data has no duplications but the list boxes are displaying the same data twice.

The code is as follows:

```
private void Show_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=XXXX");
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Number_Plate,Registered_Keeper,Make,Model,Year_Of_Make,Colour,Engine_Size,Transmission,Fuel_Type FROM datatable WHERE Number_Plate like '%" + label1.Text + "%'", conn);
            SDA.Fill(dt);
            if (SDA.Fill(dt) == 0)
            {

                button5.Visible = false;
                button4.Visible = true;
                label11.Visible = true;
                Show.Visible = false;
                button3.Visible = true;
                Make.Visible = false;
                Model.Visible = false;
                Year_Of_Make.Visible = false;
                Colour.Visible = false;
                Engine_Size.Visible = false;
                Transmission.Visible = false;
                Fuel_Type.Visible = false;
                Registered_Keeper.Visible = false;
                Plate.Visible = false;
                label2.Visible = false;
                label3.Visible = false;
                label4.Visible = false;
                label5.Visible = false;
                label6.Visible = false;
                label7.Visible = false;
                label8.Visible = false;
                label9.Visible = false;
                label12.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Plate.DataSource = dt;
                Plate.DisplayMember = "Number_Plate";

                Make.DataSource = dt;
                Make.DisplayMember = "Make";

                Model.DataSource = dt;
                Model.DisplayMember = "Model";

                Year_Of_Make.DataSource = dt;
                Year_Of_Make.DisplayMember = "Year_Of_Make";

                Colour.DataSource = dt;
                Colour.DisplayMember = "Colour";

                Engine_Size.DataSource = dt;
                Engine_Size.DisplayMember = "Engine_Size";

                Transmission.DataSource = dt;
                Transmission.DisplayMember = "Transmission";

                Fuel_Type.DataSource = dt;
                Fuel_Type.DisplayMember = "Fuel_Type";

                Registered_Keeper.DataSource = dt;
                Registered_Keeper.DisplayMember = "RegIstered_Keeper";

                Show.Visible = false;
                button3.Visible = true;
            }

        }
```

Note: When I add the data in SQL the primary key is missing about 20 numbers, so my data is 20 cars, but when I add a new one its primary key is around 50.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you do `SDA.Fill(dt)` twice. Try removing the one on the line before the if.

```
...
SqlDataAdapter SDA = ...
if (SDA.Fill(dt) == 0)
...
```

Comment: Just for completeness - one could also define the `DataTable` to have a primary key and then calling fill multiple times will update the table rather than append new rows. Also... Sql injection: "...WHERE Number_Plate like '%" + label1.Text + "%'".

Comment: Correct, on both accounts.

Answer (score 1):

you are calling `SDA.Fill(dt);` twice, once outside, once inside the if statement,

Answer (score 1):

SDA.Fill(dt) was called 2 times, try to change it to dt.count < 1